# Why is this template not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I get an error when starting my Express server and calling the side. Any Ideas whats wrong about the syntax. The startzeit is a Date() Object.

```
<tbody>
          <% for (let seminar in seminare){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= seminar.titel %></td>
                <td><%= seminar.startzeit.getDate() %>.<%= seminar.startzeit.getMonth()+1 %>.
                <%= seminar.startzeit.getFullYear() %></td>
                <td><%= seminar.ort %></td>
            </tr>
         <% }; %>
        </tbody>
```

Thats how I call the Template:

```
res.render('Seminare', {seminare: model.seminare});
```

I get the data from an model which has an Array of Objects which have this properties.

The error message I get is:

```
TypeError: /Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/praktikum12/seminarApp-v2/views/Seminare.ejs:51
    49|             <tr>
    50|                 <td><%= seminar.titel %></td>
 >> 51|                 <td><%= seminar.startzeit.getDate() %>.<%= seminar.startzeit.getMonth()+1 %>.
    52|                 <%= seminar.startzeit.getFullYear() %></td>
    53|                 <td><%= seminar.ort %></td>
    54|             </tr>

Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:23:44)
    at returnedFn (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/praktikum12/seminarApp-v2/routes/seminare.js:7:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Atom/Web-Praktika/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

When I add console.log before render I get:

```
Seminar {
    titel: 'Unternehmensgründung',
    name: 'Unternehmensgründung',
    ort: 'dortmund',
    startzeit: 2019-01-20T11:00:00.000Z,
    endzeit: 2019-02-20T13:00:00.000Z,
    freiePlaetze: 10,
    gesamtePlaetze: 22,
    tutoren: [ 'amk1' ],
    getBplaetze: [Function]
  },
  Seminar {
    titel: 'Unternehmensgründung',
    name: 'Unternehmensgründung',
    ort: 'dortmund',
    startzeit: 2019-02-20T11:00:00.000Z,
    endzeit: 2019-03-20T14:00:00.000Z,
    freiePlaetze: 5,
    gesamtePlaetze: 20,
    tutoren: [ 'bruh' ],
    getBplaetze: [Function]
  }
```

Comment: What have you done to verify that `startzeit` is a `Date` as you claim? Because it's evident that it's actually `undefined` at this point.

Comment: I did nothing to verify that should this happen trough module.exports of my model class?

Comment: Just add `console.log(model.seminare)` before your `res.render(...)`.

Comment: I have done and I added the it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs at the `for` loop.

Please see the difference below:

**for ... in**

```
for (let index in array) {
   let item = array[index];
   console.log(item);
}
```

**for ... of**

```
for (let item of array) {
   console.log(item);
}
```

What you need is the `for ... of` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of the entries in `model.seminare` don;t have `startzeit` property. Try adding an if block to check if `seminar` has `startzeit` property.

```
<%if (seminar.startzeit != undefined) { %>
    <td><%= seminar.startzeit.getDate() %>.<%= seminar.startzeit.getMonth()+1 %>.
    <%= seminar.startzeit.getFullYear() %></td>
<% } %>
```